# Can 16bit product throughoutput be doubled without specific instructions?

Tags: math, computer-science

Specific CPUs that supports 32 bit product is assumed. The application of this problem is memory bound so the accuracy loss is assumed to be beneficial.

I have two 32bits integers a and b, 4 16bits integers c1,c2,d1,d2
Let

```
c = a*b
 a = 2^16 * c1 + d1
 b = 2^16 * c2 + d2
```

Mathematically if I only get c, can I get c1*c2 and d1*d2 from c without calculating them one more time, while keeping not too bad time performance of product.

Note that in the modern cpus or gpus, 16bit multiply may be supported by specific instructions. This discussion is for general concepts only.

Comment: Is the result of the multiplication 32 bit → 64 bit or 32 bit → 32 bit?

Comment: Let’s assume the program locates at a 32bits OS.

Comment: (hint: try distributing the product `a×b = (2¹⁶×c₁+d₁)×(2¹⁶×c₂+d₂)`)

Comment: In that case, 64bit multiply may be needed. This will enable 64bit product to get 16bit product. If the OS does not support 64bit product, or if the application is for GPUs, the calculating efficiency may be, 1) direct 32bit mul to get  c1*c2, d1*d2 with two instructions plus four 16->32 conventions. 2) 64bit mul plus 16->64 covertions, plus two shift operations. Since 64bit mul efficiency may be half of 32bit mul in some hardware(e.g, Nvidia Tesla) or could be 1/8 performace ( e.g., some Nvidia GTX). This may not be the best solution.